# I want to convert/sell/trade my BEP20 Token to ETH

Tags: tokens, ether, metamask

I'm quite new when it comes to Crypto. I recently bought ETH from Binance but it, unfortunately, became a token on the Binance Smart Chain network on Metamask.

[image: ETH became a token I couldn't redeem]

What should I do? I have about 0.006 ETH in the Ethereum Mainnet Network, but I can't convert/sell/trade the BEP20 tokens because they're essentially in different networks and I have 0 BNB to convert it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BNB is the Binance ecosystem's native utility token, which can be used both for BSC and BC. BNB is mainly used to pay for transaction fees on the BC and Binance DEX platform, staking and asset transfers.

You need BNB to move funds or interact with any contract, otherwise your funds are stuck there.